# Ошибка загрузки ресурсов Google ботом (или "другая ошибка"). Как решить?

Tags: битрикс, веб-сервер, seo, google-search

Частенько при проверке сайта инструментами Google в вебмастере "Проверка URL" или в "mobile-friendly".
Имеем проблему с загрузкой ресурсов: js, css, изображения.
Причем сам инструмент пишет расплывчатую формулировку "Другая ошибка". Судя по скриншоту, который делает сам Google, видно что стили и картинки не загрузились.
Сайт работает на CMS Bitrix, на сервере работает BitrixVM, мощности хватает.

1. В чем проблема и как её решить?
2. Не влияет ли это на продвижение и позиции сайта в поисковой выдачи?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема больше не в сайте, а в самом боте Google, он экономит свои ресурсы при проверке страницы: время и трафик.

- html-код страницы должен быть короткой до 1000 строк кода
- Подключаемые ресурсы должны быстро загружаться и иметь малый вес.

Большие объемные сайты решают эту проблему путем CDN - робот выделяет дополнительные ресурсы для сканирования стороннего сайта. А стили загружают не отдельным файлом, а в head кодом .

Моё решение оказалось таким: изначально при посещение страницы пользователю по lazyload загружались 10 первых картинок, причем картинки для робота довольно большие: 350x350 (товары). Уменьшив число подгрузки картинок до 6 (120-200 кб и 100-200 мс экономии) - удалось практически (бывают исключения) полностью избавиться от такой проблемы как "другая ошибка".